# How to access nested data Values in D3

Tags: arrays, d3.js

I have nested my data like this

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Country; })
  .entries(CSV);
```

and have found that I can access the values of my array if I use this function when I bind the data

```
name.selectAll('.name')
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;   <--- Accesses the nested data
    })
     .text(function(d) {
      return d.Name;     <--- Nested value
    })
```

However I am having trouble using this elsewhere in my project. Another nested value that I need is a string called ['starting point']. How can I can access this value to use in this d3.filter() for example?

```
var filter = nested_data.filter(function(d) {
    return ("Island" == d['starting point'])
});
```

I'd like to try: d.values['starting point']

or even creating a new variable

var nested_values = nested_data(function(d) { return d.values});

but none of this is valid. What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your data on the nested data like this:

```
nested_data.map(function(m) {
  //for each group do the filter on each value
  m.values = m.values.filter(function(d) {
    //return true for those having starting point as island.
    return d['starting point'] == 'Island';
  })
})
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/jp90dssj/1/)

Comment: I wasn't expecting that, thank again. I'm finding it really hard to find examples on this. What can I do when I'm running into this yet again:
nested_data.forEach(function(d) {
     if (uniqueLocations.indexOf(d['starting point']) < 0)
       uniqueLocations.push(d['starting point'])
   });

Comment: do something like this `var unique = [];
nested_data.map(function(m) {
  m.values.forEach(function(d) {
   if (unique.indexOf(d['starting point']) < 0)
     unique.push(d['starting point']);//add since not there in teh array
  })
})
`
fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/jp90dssj/2/